# backbone:CRUD - (create)Post Data - save is not a function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-routing

i have created a backbone model like mentioned below

```
LoginModel = Backbone.View.extend({
            initialize: function(){

            },
            defaults:{
                username: 'XXXXX@XXXXX.com',
                password: 'XXXXXXXXX'
            },
            urlRoot: 'https://XXXXX.portnumber/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/',
            url: 'xxxxxxxxxx'


        });
```

I am creating a login model instance and calling the method Save

```
var loginmodel = new LoginModel();
                loginmodel.save({username:'xxxxxxx',password:'xxxxxxxx'},{
                success: function(model, response){

                    console.log('success saved'+response);
                },
                error: function(model, response){
                    consoloe.log('failed saved'+response);
                }});
```

Here i am getting an error

```
[06:22:39.742] TypeError: loginmodel.save is not a function
```

its not calling the backbone's save method to post the data to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eh... I think you extend the wrong class, it should be a model, right?

```
LoginModel = Backbone.View.extend({
```

this line create a view, not a model. Backbone's View don't have save() method, so you got that error. You need:

```
LoginModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
```

and try other staff again.